# git does not return tags

Tags: git, groovy, github-actions

I have a program (Gradle) that calls `git describe --tags --abbrev=0` in a sub-process (Java Process) within a daemon process. This tag is used to calculate a version number for builds and file names.

On Windows this works as expected (no errors, correct output). Whoever when GitHub Actions runs (Windows and Ubuntu), I don't get any tag back and this causes an exception.

Here is the specific code that fails (throws exception):

```java
static def getTag() {
    String tag = "git describe --tags --abbrev=0".execute().text;
    if (tag.isEmpty())
        throw new IllegalStateException("No tag present.");
    return tag;
}
```

And here are the GitHub Actions (up to the point of failure)

```yaml
- name: Checkout
  uses: actions/checkout@v2
- name: Validate Gradle wrapper
  uses: gradle/wrapper-validation-action@v1
- name: Setup JDK ${{ matrix.java }}
  uses: actions/setup-java@v1
  with:
    java-version: ${{ matrix.java }}
- name: Make Gradle wrapper executable
  if: ${{ runner.os != 'Windows' }}
  run: chmod +x ./gradlew
# Test
- name: Build
  run: ./gradlew build
```

Originally I used `git tag` which also returned an empty string. Also tried running specifically in bash. What do I need to do to get the last tag? Any ideas for things to try are greatly appreciated! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about adding `fetch-depth: 0` to get all tags? actions/checkout fetches only a single commit by default.
https://github.com/actions/checkout#fetch-all-history-for-all-tags-and-branches

Comment: Was unaware checkout did not include other commits, thank you!